# Query mysql com join de subquery

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando criar uma *query* que eu possa filtrar as vendas que possuem notas emitidas, na minha estrutura existem 2 tabelas: a tabela vendas e a tabela *nfe*. As duas são relacionadas pelo campo `cod_venda`.

Como posso fazer?

```
  SELECT v.cod_venda
  FROM vendas v

  JOIN
     ( SELECT COUNT(num_nfe) AS qnt_notas
            , cod_venda
         FROM nfe
        GROUP 
           BY nfe.cod_venda 
     ) notas
    ON nota.cod_venda = v.cod_venda
 WHERE  notas.qnt_notas > 0 
   AND nfe.status in ('emitida', 'cancelada')
```

Answer (score 1):

Só um pouco diferente do que você ja fez,

```
SELECT v.cod_venda, COALESCE(notas.qnt_notas, 0) qnt_notas
FROM vendas v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(num_nfe) qnt_notas, cod_venda
           FROM nfe
           WHERE status IN ('emitida','cancelada')
           GROUP BY cod_venda) notas ON notas.cod_venda = v.cod_venda
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas fazendo o teste notei que dessa forma quando não existir nenhum dado correspondente na tabela de notas a consulta não retorna nenhum registro, ou seja, se a venda não tiver nota ela não será mostrada, teria alguma ideia de como contornar essa situação?-

Comment: No lugar de `JOIN`, coloque `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Se bem que, se a venda não tiver notas, não faz sentido contar as notas, não é verdade?

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Então.. a função desta query seria para listar as vendas com notas e sem notas, para tal eu preciso fazer essa comparação entre as duas tabelas, a dificuldade é que algumas vendas podem ter mais de uma nota, senão daria para fazer um gatilho e gravar o codigo da nota na tabela de vendas... vou continuar tentando aqui, mesmo com o left join não funcionou, o having não obedece ao filtro.

Comment: Obrigado, agora funcionou!